# Access to complex javascript object properties,

Tags: javascript

I have that object sample `pages`:

```
{
"page_1":
   {
     "stats":
       {
         "stat_1": 20,
         "stat_2": 40
       }
     "ahkam":
       {
         //Staff
       }
   }
"page_2":
   {
      //staff
   }
}
```

How can i get access to the value of `stat_2`?
I used that expression but i don't know why it does not work:

```
Object.keys(pages["page_1"].stats)["stat_1"]
```

Comment: "that expression"? What expression?

Comment: Sorry, i ve corrected it

Comment: whats the name of the object that contains the objects?

Comment: What's with the `Object.keys`? Why not just `pages.page_1.stats.stat_1`?

Comment: page_x is a key, I need to parse the "pages" object through it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a visualisation of the data:

[image]

Therefore, to get there, you'd use:

```
var stat = pages.page_1.stats.stat_2;
```

If "`page_1`" is dynamic, then you can use the [bracket notation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1) (also known as the subscript notation):

```
var key = 'page_' + x;
var stat = pages[key].stats.stat_2;
```

If "`stat_2`" is also dynamic, then again, you can use the same notation:

```
var pageKey = 'page_' + x;
var statKey = 'stat_' + n;
var stat = pages[pageKey].stats[statKey];
```

Or you could use this notation for the whole expression:

```
var stat = pages[pageKey]['stats'][statKey];
```

Basically, `a.b.c` is equivalent to `a['b']['c']`, where in this case `'b'` and `'c'` are string literals, but can be any expression.

Comment: page_1 is a variable, it is the key of parsing the object, it is in string format

Comment: @HoussemBdr, alright, then use the subscript notation. Example updated.

Comment: FYI, it's called *bracket notation*. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1

Comment: @FelixKling, it has many names, apparently. Crockford uses the term ["subscript notation"](http://javascript.crockford.com/survey.html). So if someone is looking it up, they should probably try both versions. Anyway, answer updated with both versions, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

as

```
obj = { 
       field1: {
                stat1: "string";
       }
}


obj.field1.stat1
```

Answer (score 0):

is this not enough,
Assign that object to `var Page = {....}`

```
  Page.page_1.stats.stat_1
```